# Proper LaTeX3 syntax for \usepackage{<name of .sty file>} - \ProvidesPackage{<name of .sty file>}

Tags: expl3

The `MWE_1` defines a `document command` which in turn calls a `\cs_` macro. Both are defined in the document's `preamble` section sandwiched between `\ExplSyntaxOn` `\ExplSyntaxOff` statements, as is the declaration of the associated local and global variables. There seems to be little reason to define document commands for the purpose of using them in a single document, and no reason whatsoever to develop `\cs_` macros with that scope in mind, hence I usually work with a number of `.sty` files. For the purpose of demonstration let the preamble of `MWE_1` be packaged in the file `\myCommandsAndMacros.sty` which is headed with the instruction `\ProvidesPackage{myCommandsAndMacros}` and in `MWE_2` loaded with the instruction `\usepackage{myCommandsAndMacros}` - not sure where in the distant past I gleaned this process from, but it works. To my surprise I now learn (see Part II in the `LaTeX3 Interfaces` document) that `\ProvidesPackage` is an instruction that belongs to `LaTeX2` (although it may be used by `LaTeX3`), but all attempts to modify the syntax I have been using to `\ProvidesExplPackage{myCommandsAndMacros}` fail with error `!Paragraph ended before \ProvidesExplPackage was complete`.

`MWE_1:`

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions,enable-debug]{expl3}
%   or: \RequirePackage[check-declarations,log-functions,enable-debug]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   Variable Declarations:
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\int_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_int
\int_new:N \g_rn_Result_int

\cs_new:Npn \rnUtils_Squared:n #1
  {
\group_begin:
      \int_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_int {#1}
      \int_gset:Nn \g_rn_Result_int {\int_eval:n {\l_rn_auxOne_int     *\l_rn_auxOne_int}}
\group_end:
  }  %  \rnUtils_Squared:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myDocumentCommand{O{911}O{abc}}
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_int {#1}
    \rnUtils_Squared:n {\l_rn_auxOne_int}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#2}
    \int_use:N \g_rn_Result_int,~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
  }  %  \myDocumentCommand

\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myDocumentCommand[2][$\alpha$]

  \myDocumentCommand
\end{document}
```

`MWE_2:`

```
\documentclass{article}
%-----------------------
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions,enable-debug]{expl3}
%   or: \RequirePackage[check-declarations,log-functions,enable-debug]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{myCommandsAndMacros}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myDocumentCommand[2][$\alpha$]

  \myDocumentCommand
\end{document}
```

`myCommandsAndMacros.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{myCommandsAndMacros}
%\ProvidesExplPackage{myCommandsAndMacros}  ==> ERROR
% ===========================================================
\ExplSyntaxOn

%   Variable Declarations:
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\int_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_int
\int_new:N \g_rn_Result_int

\cs_new:Npn \rnUtils_Squared:n #1
  {
\group_begin:
      \int_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_int {#1}
      \int_gset:Nn \g_rn_Result_int {\int_eval:n {\l_rn_auxOne_int   *\l_rn_auxOne_int}}
\group_end:
  }  %  \rnUtils_Squared:n

\NewDocumentCommand\myDocumentCommand{O{911}O{abc}}
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_int {#1}
    \rnUtils_Squared:n {\l_rn_auxOne_int}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#2}
    \int_use:N \g_rn_Result_int,~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
  }  %  \myDocumentCommand

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I don't know and I haven't read the question yet, but `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `Off` is likely not needed in an expl package.

Comment: If you use the L3 version, isn't expl syntax automatically  toggled on?

Comment: You need `\RequirePackage{expl3} \ProvidesExplPackage ...`.  And you probably also want to add `\RequirePackage{xparse}`.

Comment: `\ProvidesExplPackage` takes four arguments: `\ProvidesExplPackage{<package>}{<date>}{<version>}{<description>}` not just one and an optional argument like `\ProvidesPackage{<package>}[<version and date info>]`. Cf. also https://www.texdev.net/2011/12/11/programming-latex3-the-programming-environment/

Comment: Off-topic: you have non-expandable material, so you need `\cs_new_protected:Npn` not `\cs_new:Npn`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike `\ProvidesPackage`, which uses a single argument for several different pieces of data, `\ProvidesExplPackage` has a separate argument for each. For example

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage {siunitx} {2018-07-21} {3.0.0-alpha}
  {A comprehensive (SI) units package}
% Here, `expl3` syntax is active
```

Comment: Hello, according to my interface3.pdf (dated 2019-02-15), “The
〈date〉 should be given in the format 〈year〉/〈month〉/〈day〉.” Are both formats accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Well, after trying it, the log file shows either dashes or slashes depending on what was used in the second argument of `\ProvidesExplPackage`. So, maybe this should be tightened up a bit for consistency...

Comment: @frougon https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews27.pdf says: "LaTeX has used a date format in the form `yyyy/mm/dd`. [...] [T]here is another date format, formalised by the International Standard ISO 8601. The basic format defined by this standard is functionally equivalent to the LaTeX format, but using `-` rather than `/`. [...] From this release, LaTeX will accept ISO format date strings in the date argument of `\ProvidesPackage`, `\usepackage`, etc. [...] The new functionality can be seen in the startup banner which advertises `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>`."

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @Stephen, this is helpful.